# Fetch local storage data from AppiumDriver

Tags: java, android, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

Need to set Html5 LoclaStorage value for Appium, for which I am trying to fetch local storage value with below code

```
WebStorage webStorage = (WebStorage) driver;
LocalStorage localStorage = webStorage.getLocalStorage();
System.out.println("localStorage is"+localStorage.size());
```

I am getting below exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver cannot be cast to class org.openqa.selenium.html5.WebStorage (io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver and org.openqa.selenium.html5.WebStorage are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

Driver used is AppiumDriver

```
AppiumDriver<WebElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(new URL(url), desiredCapabilities);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Able to achieve setting up local storage values in appium using context switching.

1. Context Switching to WEB_VIEW
2. Use JavascripExecutor to set the localstorage property and change to native view to perform appium testing.

```
Set<String> contextNames = driver.getContextHandles();
for (String contextName : contextNames) {
System.out.println("Inside "+contextName); //prints out something like NATIVE_APP \n WEBVIEW_1
}
System.out.println(driver.getContext());
driver.context("WEBVIEW"); // set context to WEBVIEW_1
```